# How to make VSCode and Prettier extension to ignore React JSX element's white-spaces?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, prettier

noob here. I recently got a new pc and now i've been having issues with visual studio code and prettier extension. So far, when on save file either Prettier ext or VsCode automictically, put JSX elements in 1 line. Look at examples below

what i want below:

```
<Card.Title>
   Company name (symbol)
</Card.Title>
```

what vscode or prettier ext does on save:

```
<Card.Title>Company name (symbol)</Card.Title>
```

Any help or link would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [point of Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/why-prettier.html) is to cede control over such minor details of formatting in order to focus on more important things. If you still want to control where lines should break and so on, Prettier probably isn't for you. It's an opinionated tool, which means its formatting style isn't customizable, and it's been [intentionally made that way](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html). Don't use Prettier in that case. Remove the extension that runs it from your VS Code.